# how to connect to database

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, connection-string

I have managed to connect to a database using localhost using sqlexpress, so my connection string is correct, however I am hosted on 123-reg and cannot connect to the database I created on their server. I have tried an SQL insert and select statements to see if my website can connect to it when viewed on my website live, but it does not connect.
It is the connection that fails, I am not sure if I am linking to the server correctly.

123-reg gave me a connection string to insert into my webconfig page:

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="*****; Database=*****; User Id=*****; Password=*****" />
```

I have tried to access this on an aspx page using:

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=*****;DataSource=*****; Initial Catalog=*****; User Id=*****; Password=*****;"

        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (note) values ('works')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        Label1.Text = "works"
    End Try
```

Comment: Is it the connection or insert that fails? Can you provide some information from the exception?

Comment: I would think it is the connection string because my SQL statements worked on my local server db

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The first set of "***" in the connection string they gave you...does it contain a "server="?

Comment: Thi is what they give me: Provider=sqloledb;

Comment: So does it get passed the Open method call? From what I remember I think Open throws an exception if it can't connect. Is it possible to connect through Sql Management Studio? Not all providers allow this, but it should validate if your server name/username/password is correct.

Comment: In webconfig it has: Server=ATLAS-SQL-07;

Comment: I looked into this, 123 reg do not support connecting to external applications like sql manager so I cannot test it

Comment: You should add to your question what the error message is that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

They give you: `Provider SqlOleDb`,

This means that you should use the OleDb classes (`OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand` etc.) not the classes in the SqlClient namespace (`SqlConnection, SqlCommand` etc).

If this is true and they do not offer an alternative to a more updated Sql Native Client, I think you have to change your code to use these classes (or change provider)